# How to construct a projector using its intrinsics matrix?

Tags: rendering, camera, transforms

A projector can be regarded as an inverse camera, since the image projection is a reverse process of image captured. So the projecor also has its intrinsics and distortion coefficients just like a camera:
$$
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{x} & s & c_{x}\\
0 & f_{y} & x_{y}\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
D=[k1, k2, k3, p1, p2]
$$
Is there any way to construct a realistc projecter using these pararmeters instead of a simple spot light in blender?